# Filtering parameters by pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, parameters

I want to filter certain params from the logs using this line found in the `filter_parameter_logging.rb` initializer:

`config.filter_parameters += [:parameter_name]`

The problem is the params I want to filter are variable, but do follow a certain pattern such as this:

`example_param1`
`example_param2`
`example_param3`
`example_param4`
etc.

How can I go about using `config.filter_parameters` to filter parameters by pattern, rather than explicit strings? Or how else might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters filter works by partial matching regular expression. You can add regular expressions to that array

`config.filter_parameters += [/example_param\d+/]`